# Key Value Observe static NSDictionary on facade class

Tags: ios, objective-c, observer-pattern, nsmutabledictionary, key-value-observing

I have a `ServiceFacade` class with class methods for communicating with backend services.
On that `ServiceFacade` class I have a static method that returns `NSMutableDictionary` in which I keep current `ServiceFacade`'s downloading operations.
I want to observer changes on this `NSMutableDictionary` either in `AppDelegate` or any other place. The app delegate seems not to respond to

```
- (void)addObserver:(NSObject *)anObserver
     forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
        options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options
        context:(void *)context{
```

}

Method for returning NSMutableDictionary:

```
    +(NSMutableDictionary *)downloadOperations
{
    if (_downloadOperations)
    {
        return _downloadOperations;
    }
    [_downloadOperations addObserver:[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] forKeyPath:@"downloadOperationsDict" options:0 context:NULL];
    _downloadOperations = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    return _downloadOperations;
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: KVO will only be triggered if the `_downloadOperations` pointer changes. Mutating the content of the dictionary pointed by `_downloadOperations` will **not** trigger KVO notifications.

Comment: No, it will only trigger, if `-setDownloadOperation` is executed. That's the problem.

Comment: Yes. Sorry that's what I implied but explained badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to observe `NSMutableDictionary` changes. But there are 2 workarounds

1) Subclass NSMutableDictionary and trigger Notifications on `setObject:forKey` and `removeObjectForKey`.
2) Wrap your _downloadOperations write/remove operations and trigger notifications there.

I suggest you to use 2) variant, as subclassing `NSMutableDictionary` is not so easy.

So 2) variant will be like this.
Add these 2 methods to class `ServiceFacade`

```
- (void)setDownloadObject:(id)aObj forKey:(id<NSCopying>)aKey
{
     [self.downloadOperations setObject:aObj forKey:aKey];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DownloadOperationsChanged" object:self
                                                           userInfo:self.downloadOperations];
}

- (id)removeDownloadObjectForKey:(id<NSCopying>)aKey
{
     [[self.downloadOperations] removeObjectForKey:aKey];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DownloadOperationsChanged" object:self
                                                           userInfo:self.downloadOperations];
}
```

After this, you need to add and remove objects from that dictionary via this 2 methods. And you can also subscribe for changes

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(downloadOperationsChanged:)
                                                 name:@"DownloadOperationsChanged"
                                               object:nil];
    return YES;
}

- (void)downloadOperationsChanged:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"Operations : %@", aNotification);
}
```

Comment: This was my backup solution. Thank you for the anwser!